# Sniffing https traffic of an android app

Tags: android, https, apk, sniffing

I want to do a challenge: automise some tasks that I do in a game so I can get the max of points.

To do that, I need to know the url called and the parameters that are used in the Game. After setting a genymotion station and made a proxy, I've discovered that the game won't start if the certificate doesn't match with the one that is set in the app.

So my question is how I can go further?

Comment: as a next step I would suggest you to call your lawyer

Comment: This question may better fit https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "won't start if the certificate doesn't match with the one that is set in the app" - Possibly, the app does not include its own certificate but relies on Android to handle HTTPS based on the built-in root certificates. You may be able to add your own certificate to your device's trusted certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 application

1.[charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)

2.[fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that the application won't start because it checks the certificates.